# Unknown app icon in iPhone

Tags: iphone, applications

I was organising my app screen on my iPhone SE. I move the apps around till I am satisfied. Once I was done, I got this app icon (red circled on the screenshot) on my main screen.

It doesn't open, if I touch it for long, the other apps start to wiggle in their place, but this doesn't respond at all.

What is this and How do I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: The icon represents an app which is pending download. Make sure you are connected to the Internet. Try restarting your iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting your phone may resolve the issue.